# Esperar execuçoes pendentes terminarem para prosseguir, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

isso foi o exemplo mais pratico que encontrei.. é um exemplo em que o servidor envia 2 mensagens (ou mais) seguidas e ao "mesmo tempo", ele nao checa se há algo sendo executado, no caso se houvesse ele deveria esperar até o fim para enviar a nova requisição.

Pensei em criar um loop finito que espera uma variável ficar `false` para prosseguir, a variável seria a que diz que o trabalho da ultima requisição "acabou" mas acho que isso é gambiarra.

```
    // CONFIGURACOES DA DB //
var db = new Dexie('teste');

db.version(1).stores({
    sequences: '++id,of'
});
db.open().
catch ();
// CONFIGURACOES DA DB //

var executionOrder = []; // tem como deixar vazio sem ter undefined?

// isso foi o exemplo mais pratico que encontrei.. é um exemplo em que o servidor envia 4 mensagens (ou mais) seguidas e ao "mesmo tempo", ele nao checa se há algo sendo executado, no caso se houvesse ele deveria esperar até o fim para enviar a nova requisiçao

setInterval(function () {
    var newOrder = ['NOVO'].reverse();
    executionOrder = executionOrder.concat(newOrder);
    execute('INIT');
}, 4000);

setInterval(function () {
    var newOrder = ['APAGA'].reverse();
    executionOrder = executionOrder.concat(newOrder);
    execute('INIT');
}, 4000);

setInterval(function () {
    var newOrder = ['NOVO'].reverse();
    executionOrder = executionOrder.concat(newOrder);
    execute('INIT');
}, 4000);

function execute(req) {
    if (req == 'INIT') {
        callback();
    }  if (req == 'NOVO') {
        db.sequences.add({
            of: '0'
        });
        console.log('ADD 1');
        callback();
    }  if (req == 'APAGA') {
        db.sequences.where("of").equalsIgnoreCase('0').each(function (seq) {
            db.sequences.delete(seq.id);
        }).then(function () {
            console.log('DEL ALL');
            callback();
        });
    }
};

function callback() {
    if (executionOrder.length) {
        var next = executionOrder.pop();
        execute(next);
    }
}
```

se voce tirar um `setInterval` vai observar que tudo ocorre bem.. Mas com 2 ou mais ele nao espera..

Exemplo funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/uxnry1m6/

Comment: Por favor, contextualize sua pergunta. Isso executa no cliente? Servidor NodeJS? Requisições são vindas de vários clientes? Único cliente? Websocket?

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira isso é executado no cliente, os setinterval representam mensagens vindas do servidor Websocket que é tratada pelo `OnMessage` que neste é representado pelo SetInterval. A função execute é quem trata as mensagens recebidas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ideia geral de usar uma variável como "semáforo" está OK (mas usar ela num *loop* seria mesmo gambiarra, e não funcionaria), e da forma como seu código está estruturado pode-se fazer isso com um mínimo de esforço:

1. Crie a variável, inicialmente permitindo qualquer execução:

   ```
   var semaforo = true; // Aberto
   ```
2. Quando você for executar alguma coisa demorada e assíncrona, feche o semáforo:

   ```
   if (req == 'APAGA') {
       semaforo = false; // Fechado
       db.sequences.where("of").equalsIgnoreCase('0').each(function (seq) {
           db.sequences.delete(seq.id);
       }).then(function () {
           console.log('DEL ALL');
           semaforo = true; // A execução demorada acabou, aberto de novo
           callback();
       });
   }
   ```

   Não se esqueça de fazer isso para toda operação assíncrona, fechando o semáforo **antes** dela começar (e não no meio).
3. Por fim, antes de executar qualquer coisa verifique se o semáforo está aberto:

   ```
   function callback() {
       if (semaforo && executionOrder.length) {
   ```

   Se não estiver, ele não executa. Mas e aí, quando ele vai executar? Simples: como você chama o *callback* no final de cada execução, ele vai verificar de novo se existem operações pendentes e fazê-las.

No seu caso, isso é suficiente. Mas para deixar tudo mais robusto, eu sugiro que você modifique o *callback* para executar não apenas uma, mas **todas** as ações pendentes, uma por vez (não se preocupe com a concorrência, o semáforo garante que cada operação espere a última estar concluída):

```
function callback() {
    while (semaforo && executionOrder.length) {
        var next = executionOrder.pop();
        execute(next);
    }
}
```

P.S. Encontrei também um problema na forma como você está implementando uma fila, inverter uma lista e usá-la como pilha funciona bem - desde que você não acrescente mais elementos a ela. Pois se você fizer isso, esses elementos irão para o início da fila, e não pro final, bagunçando a ordem. Em vez disso, sugiro usar a lista como fila mesmo, e não como pilha, chamando `portanto`shift`em vez de`pop`:

```
var newOrder = ['NOVO']; // Sem o .reverse()
executionOrder = executionOrder.concat(newOrder);

...

var next = executionOrder.shift(); // Em vez de .pop()
```

[Exemplo completo](http://jsfiddle.net/uxnry1m6/7/).

Comment: Tentei aplicar e nao consegui, continuo tentanto

Comment: @Elaine Você aplicou esse princípio também no caso `NOVO`? (pois o método `add` pelo jeito também é assíncrono, se você não usar o semáforo nele outra operação pode começar antes desta terminar) Ou seu código real é muito diferente desse da pergunta? (pode ser problema em algum outro lugar)

Comment: Veja eu apliquei em tudo.. http://jsfiddle.net/uxnry1m6/3/ ainda nao funciona, este codigo é o meu código real.

Comment: @Elaine o `ADD` estava aplicado errado (a chamada do *callback* estava fora do `then`). Além disso, se você quer implementar uma fila, inverter a lista e tratá-la como uma pilha só funciona uma vez - se você acrescenta mais elementos nela, a ordem fica doida. Em vez disso, use o `concat` na ordem direta mesmo, e no lugar de `pop` use `shift`. Atualizei o exemplo com essas mudanças, veja se ainda restou algum problema: http://jsfiddle.net/uxnry1m6/4/

Comment: A propósito, notei que você usa um `each` e depois dele um `then`, isso pode ser problemático (não tenho certeza, pois não tenho experiência com essa biblioteca Dexie), pois *me parece* que o `then` está sendo executado uma vez para cada elemento deletado (e não uma única vez depois que todos os elementos são deletados). Confirme isso por favor, e se for o caso posso atualizar minha resposta com uma sugestão nesse sentido.

Comment: Que mancada a minha, me desculpe, seu script funciona mas nos aspectos, mas em outro ele falha. Veja, o `then` é executado apenas quando o loop se conclui, ou seja ele só é chamado uma vez para cada requisiçao.

Comment: Que mancada a minha, me desculpe, seu script funciona mas nos aspectos, mas em outro ele falha. Veja, o `then` é executado apenas quando o loop se conclui, ou seja ele só é chamado uma vez para cada requisição. O problema que restou é: ele está agrupando as açoes de execuçao! por exemplo essa sequencia: `['NOVO', 'NOVO', 'APAGA', 'NOVO', 'APAGA'] ` ele agrupa os 3 `NOVOS` e os executa primeiro e agrupa os 2 `APAGA` e os executa em grupo depois dos `NOVOS`

Comment: @Elaine Vou tentar reproduzir isso, só um momento...

Comment: o fato dele agrupar nao pode ser ignorado por que atrapalha minhas outras execuçao, vamos a este exemplo: se eu coloco `1` na equaçao de apenas soma, e depois coloco o `2`.. mas depois resolvo apagar os numeros colocados anteriormente (`1 e 2`) e colocar os numeros `4` e `7` e realizar a equaçao o resultado teria que ser `11` mas se ele agrupar as açoes o resultado vai ser outro que nao deveria ocorrer.. entendeu né?

Comment: @Elaine Havia também um erro no `DEL`, você estava fechando o semáforo dentro do `where` e não **antes** dele. Agora tenho certeza que funciona, veja [esse exemplo mais descritivo](http://jsfiddle.net/uxnry1m6/6/). (e o [exemplo real](http://jsfiddle.net/uxnry1m6/7/))